# Finding the value of one-sided limits.

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

The [] stands for the greatest integer function.

I have calculated and the left-hand limit is coming as $(\frac{a}{b})$.
But, I have doubt in the right-hand limit.
I did this problem by sandwich-theorem.
Can, anyone help me to find the right-hand limit correctly?

Comment: What do the brackets around $\frac xb$ stand for?

Comment: @ Henning Makholm greatest integer function.

Answer (score 1):

If $\bigl[\frac xb\bigr]$ means the greatest integer $\le\frac xb$ -- that is, the floor of $\frac xb$ -- then the limit from the right is obviously $0$, because $\bigl[\frac xb\bigr]=0$ when $x\in (0,b)$.

But in that case I don't see how you get the left-sided limit to be $\frac ab$ -- because then $\bigl[ \frac xb\bigr]=-1$ when $x \in (-b,0)$, and so in this interval the limit is that of $\frac{-a}x$ which tends to infinity unless $a=0$.